# SQL Injection for PHP INSERT statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I currently have this.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO user VALUES(:email, :dob, :username, :password)");
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email_address);
$stmt->bindValue(':dob', $dateOB);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();
```

Which gives this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on bool in.
Ive seen many people say the error is infact with the prepare statement.

($connection is DB connection and 100% works as i have this query working without SQL injection).
I've tried multiple solutions online but cant seem to get it working so any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Trying turning on MySQL error reporting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/231316

Comment: One obvious problem is lack of column names section. why don't you list them? there could be other problems tho, and you need error reporting to see them